# Android bluetooth broadcast, Galaxy Gear appliccation

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am creating application for Samsung Galaxy Gear.

I want to do communication between Android phone (note3) application and Galaxy Gear Android application through broadcast receiver or Bluetooth broadcast receiver.

I have also tried to do broadcasting between two applications. Broadcasting is working if I install both applications on the same device. When I install sender and receiver application on two different device which are connected via Bluetooth then broadcasting is not working.

Please can anyone tell me how other Galaxy Gear applications communicate with phone applications (Evernote, Banjo, Snapchat)?

Comment: There is no public SDK for writing applications for the Galaxy Gear at this time. If you are using Samsung's private SDK, please contact your Samsung representative for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved the problem by lowering permission levels. The apps must be signed by the same certificate, otherwise they will not communicate with each other, but if you removed the permissions security, it should work. Do this for testing only, as this should be resolved by itself once it goes to production.